# i18next plugin to find keys for translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, i18next

I use i18next to localize my React application. I have to go through all the files to find keys for translation. Is there some plugin, which find all keys and return one file with that keys for translation?
Something similar to Flask-Babel.

Comment: Don’t know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I misread the docs. Package is i18next-parser.